# How to replace onclick event with GreaseMonkey?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

This website has a gallery of images.  Each time I click on a thumbnail image it opens the URL in a new tab (not because I set firefox to open links in new tabs).  I want to just open the URL in the same window.  An example of what the thumbnail images looks like is this.

```
<span class="thumb" id="789">
<a href="/post/image/12345" onclick="return PostMenu.click(12345)">
<img  class="preview" src="http://abc.com/image.jpg" title="title" alt="">
</a>
</span>
```

I believe that `onclick="return PostMenu.click(12345)"` is doing this.  How can I replace the `PostMenu.click()` function with my own empty function in GreaseMonkey? Is there a way to make a GreaseMonkey script intercept all onclick events?

My only other option is to go through all the `span` classes and remove the `onclick="return PostMenu.click(12345)"` from the link tags.  But since there can be over a hundred of these on a single page, I'd rather not do that.

Comment: What's the code of `PostMenu.click`, does it more than `window.open()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, deleting the `onclick`s is not at all an onerous task.

With jQuery, the code would merely be:

```
$("span.thumb a").prop ("onclick", null);
```

Or, for older versions of jQuery:

```
$("span.thumb a").removeAttr ("onclick");
```

A complete script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Kill select onClicks
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$("span.thumb a").prop ("onclick", null);
```

The advantage of this approach is that:
(1) You preserve `PostMenu.click()` in case you want it, or it's needed, elsewhere,
(2) You are removing crud from the page, which makes it just a little bit less unwieldy.
(3) I suspect that you might also need to unwrap or modify that link -- in which case, the targeted rewrite approach using jQuery is the way to go.

---

If you really just want to replace the `PostMenu.click()` function with your own empty function, the code for that is just:

```
unsafeWindow.PostMenu.click = function () {};
```

As for having Greasemonkey intercept all `onclick` events...  That is not easy to do reliably.  Forget that approach unless there is an overwhelming need for some reason (which there doesn't seem to be, in this case).

Comment: Just wondering, for the `prop` script, as soon as the page loads... is it immediately executed? And does it actually remove the `onclick` attribute? I tested it and it doesn't open in a new tab anymore but when I checked the source, the `onclick` attribute was still there.  One minor issue is that the site has auto paging so as I scroll down, more thumbnails are generated so the `prop` script does not work on the newly populated thumbnails.  The second script works fine though.

Comment: Actually thinking about it, I guess the reason it opens in a new tab was due to the auto paging since pressing back makes it have to reload from the beginning.  Turning auto paging off, clicking links opens in same tab.

Comment: Yes, the `prop` code only fires once, and links added by AJAX after the initial page load are not effected.  You can make a script to check for and remove the `onclicks` as they appear, but it sounds like you've already got a workaround and/or the empty-function approach.