# Developing a browser extension for Chrome and Firefox to hook into Button events

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I know this is quite broad question but I want to ask about developing a browser extension for Chrome and Firefox, specifically if this is something that can be done without rocket science. The core concept of what I need to do is to have a way to hook into specific button when on a specific page that it will prevent its default behavior first, instead show a Form Modal which loads a URL from third-part (external) site possibly (iframe) or something. Then the Form Modal have this function to validate if reference number or license number is valid before allowing the actual button (in the main page) to be clickable.

The case here is that the web app is already done (a SaaS), and it is almost impossible to extend through API so we will need to hook into it and inject the project the is described above.

This may look like a malicious extension but basically it will be used not for that but for a eCommerce site as third-party integration.

Comment: You can definitely inject scripts onto the page from an extension, just remember that the global context of your script would be different than the page so it might be difficult if the page utilizes different frameworks.

Comment: I think this can be done even with a userscript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace onclick event with GreaseMonkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349193/how-to-replace-onclick-event-with-greasemonkey)